# Are temporary tables in postgresql visible over all client sessions?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, postgresql-performance

I want to create a temp table so as to be able to join it to a few tables because joining those tables with the content of the proposed temporary table takes a lot of time (fetching the content of the temporary table is time consuming.Repeating it over and over takes more and more time). I am dropping the temporary table when my needs are accomplished.
I want to know if these temporary tables would be visible over other client session(my requirement is to make them visible only for current client session). I am using postgresql. It would be great if you could suggest better alternatives to the solution I am thinking of.

Comment: you have two good answers, but also bear in mind that in postgresql temporary tables are very very rarely used. There's always a better way

Comment: Can you please suggest what other approach might I take?I tried using CTEs but the data in the CTEs are not stored and hence they do not give major performance boost(in certain cases ,as in mine, they can deteriorate the performance).

Comment: If you have a problem with performance then please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then ask a new question with all of the information listed in the tag info

Comment: if you have a specific issue please post a question with the query, the explain analyze output and the table structures (all as formatted text please not images)

Answer (score 10):

PostgreSQL then is the database for you. Temporary tables done better than the standard. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html),

> Although the syntax of `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` resembles that of the SQL standard, the effect is not the same. In the standard, temporary tables are defined just once and automatically exist (starting with empty contents) in every session that needs them. **PostgreSQL instead requires each session to issue its own `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` command for each temporary table to be used. This allows different sessions to use the same temporary table name for different purposes,** whereas the standard's approach constrains all instances of a given temporary table name to have the same table structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response Evan.Actually I was confused as to what these sessions really referring to .Are these DB sessions or client sessions since DB session can span multiple client sessions and if the table is visible for the entire DB session to every client (not the db client) ,its no good to me.

Comment: There is no concept of client sessions. There is only database sessions. This *could* in fact be a problem if *your* client was pooling connections. That's something for you take into account. There is no way for the database to see *your* concept of client sessions.

Answer (score 7):

Please read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TEMPORARY).

Temporary tables are only visible in the current session and are automatically dropped when the database session ends.

If you specify `ON COMMIT`, the temporary table will automatically be dropped at the end of the current transaction.

If you need good table statistics on a temporary table, you have to call `ANALYZE` explicitly, as these statistics are not collected automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response Launrenz.Actually I was confused as to what these sessions really referring to .Are these DB sessions or client sessions since DB session can span multiple client sessions and if the table is visible for the entire DB session to every client (not the db client) ,its no good to me.

Comment: It is a database session. If you use some kind of connection pooling, you either have to explicitly drop the temporary table when you are done, or you do your work in a single transaction and use `ON COMMIT` with the temporary table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , I my case user already used DROP TABLE temporary_table_name; still table unable to drop and user  getting error when he execute same query (function). user using connection pooling at application level

Comment: @AdamMulla Your comment doesn't contain enough detail for me to understand what you are talking about. Perhaps start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

By default , temporary tables are visible for current session only and temporary tables are dropped automatically after commit or closing that transaction, so you don't need to drop explicitly.

The auto vacuum daemon cannot access and therefore cannot vacuum or analyze temporary tables. For this reason, appropriate vacuum and analyze operations should be performed via session SQL commands. For example, if a temporary table is going to be used in complex queries, it is wise to run ANALYZE on the temporary table after it is populated.

Optionally, GLOBAL or LOCAL can be written before TEMPORARY or TEMP. This presently makes no difference in PostgreSQL and is deprecated