# pg: typescript error after retrieving a client from the connection pool

Tags: typescript, postgresql, pg

```
import pg, {PoolConfig} from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pg;

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.USER_NAME,
    host: process.env.HOST_NAME,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
} as PoolConfig);

export {
    pool
};
```

I am trying to retrieve a client from the postgresql connection pool and am receiving a type error when I call "client.query".  I am receiving the following error for the ".query" function, "TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'void'".  This is a typescript node.js application.

```
const client = await pool.connect();

try {
    const res = await client.query('SELECT …’, [….]);

    if (!res?.rows[0])
        return null;

    return res.rows[0];
} catch (e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    client.release();
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

I also added the package @types/pg and am not sure what could be missing.

Comment: Looks like `await pool.connect();` has a type of void? Then `const client = ...` so client is of type void

Comment: From a typescript perspective, what need to change for this to work?  Do I need to declare a type for client?  I have not been able to find a typescript example for this.

Comment: You'll need to show us where `pool` comes from and in particular what type it has.

Comment: @Bergi they already do. its type is `pg.Pool`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I copied the details you gave, installed the latest `@types/pg` package, fixed the syntax errors in your repro details, and removed the `files` field from your tsconfig because I don't understand why you're doing that. I wrapped your second code block in an async IIFE. I do not get that error. I'm using TypeScript 4.9.5. Please provide enough detail to reproduce the problem and fix the syntax errors in your repro. Provide a _**real**_ [mre].

Comment: For your reference, when I did the above, what I see in the VS Code hover tooltip for `.query` is "_`(method) ClientBase.query<any, never[]>(queryTextOrConfig: string | pg.QueryConfig<never[]>, values?: never[] | undefined): Promise<pg.QueryResult<any>> (+6 overloads)`_"

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this whole site is based on a framework of Q&A, so for the health of the framework, please ask one. You can see [ask] for guidance. Note: ['Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you're showing is not an exact 1:1 copy of the code that actually caused the error: I would expect this to happen if you attempted to mix your `connect()` calls by:

- duplicating the `connect()` call somewhere, leading to [`pool.connect()` returning a client](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pg/index.d.ts#L172), which you again call `connect()` on, which [promises a `void`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pg/index.d.ts#L213).
- trying to run one query when acquiring the connection from the pool, by giving `connect()` a callback function as argument:

  > [`pool.connect(callback: (...) => void) => void`](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#poolconnect)

  then trying to use that `connect()` result as a `pg.Client` to run another query, even though in this scenario it's `void` as indicated by the message and pointed out by [qrsngky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75553040/pg-typescript-error-after-retrieving-a-client-from-the-connection-pool#comment133298271_75553040). `pool.connect()` promises to bring back a client only when called without any arguments.

  > `pool.connect() => Promise<pg.Client>`

  One use case that comes to mind for this would be some kind of connection setup script - you could handle it [`.on()` connect or acquire events](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#events).
- exposing an altered/overloaded `connect()` when exporting from the module where you've configured and initialised the pool, making a seemingly no-arg call default to the form using a callable or duplicating the call. So either of the above, just elsewhere, hidden away.

A few double checks could be helpful, too: are you sure the `pool` you exported is the same thing you're calling `connect()` on later? Is `pg` package [the one you expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg), the version you expect?

---

As a workaround, regardless of what caused this: if you're not defining transactions inside your query, you could try to use [`pool.query()`](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#poolquery) directly:

```typescript
const res = await pool.query('SELECT …', [….]);
if (!res?.rows[0])
    return null;
return res.rows[0];
```

No need to acquire the client from the pool through `connect()` first, then `finally {client.release();}` later because `pool.query()` handles both automatically. Since the `catch` only re-throws the error and `finally` only releases the connection, the entire `try` block could be removed. That's actually what [the package author recommends](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#poolquery:%7E:text=use%20it%20exclusively%20unless%20I%20need%20a):

> I find pool.query to be a handy shortcut many situations and use it exclusively unless I need a transaction.

Comment: "*I use it exclusively unless I need a transaction.*" - how often do you not need a transaction? Whenever I do a series of queries, I want them to use the same client, and I cannot remember the last endpoint that did only a single db query.

Comment: @Bergi I suspect by "needing a transaction" brianc meant having autocommit switched off. Like most libs and clients, node-postgres has it on by default - and with it on, it doesn't actually matter which session queries run in, as long as they end up running in the intended order. If required, `pool.query()` calls can be arranged into a chain, same as `client.query()`.

Comment: Oh I missed that you were quoting the author not write this yourself. Still, there's a common case where even with auto-commit and no transactions it does matter which client you are using: when using session state, such as [temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41178844/1048572), [roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html), or [parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) (particularly the timezone). And the worst thing is: it works when there's only a single client in the pool but then fails in production under load.

Comment: @Bergi No argument there. By no means am I suggesting that `pool.query()` can be a drop-in replacement everywhere - I suggest it as a workaround for the case on hand. I'll meet your temp table, role and param and raise you a cursor, listener, table or advisory lock, prepared statement and sequence cache - basically completing the list of stuff lost on a sudden [`DISCARD ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html). I'd stop here as discussing `client.query()`-first vs. `pool.query()`-first approach and best practices for each sounds like material for a thread of its own :)